# List all installed software without booting into the OS

Tags: windows-7

We know how to [get the list of software installed](https://superuser.com/questions/447277/list-all-installed-software-on-pc) from an instance of an operating system.

My windows is unbootable. No safe mode. I want to get the list of installed software so that I can wipe and reinstall.

Comment: What stop code or bug check are you getting that windows is unbootable?

Comment: @cybernard BSOD PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_ERROR 0x000000b6. Discussed in a [Long thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/312333-process1_initialization_error-0x000000b6.html) here. Only after seeing no possible solution I decided to reinstall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

The list of installed software can be retrieved from the registry.

1. Either remove the hard drive and load it onto another system, or boot any Linux live CD/DVD/USB.
2. Copy the `SOFTWARE` file located in the `X:\Windows\System32\config`. This file contains the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` registry hive, and includes the system-wide installed software data.
3. Copy all `NTUSER.DAT` files from all `X:\Users` subfolders, and rename them after their order (e.g. `NTUSER1.DAT`, `NTUSER2.DAT`, etc.). These files contains the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry hive, and include the per-user installed software data.
4. Get all the copied files in a working Windows system, and open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).
5. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after replacing the path inside quotes:

   ```
   reg load "HKLM\SOFTWARE2" "X:\Folder\containing\SOFTWARE"
   ```
6. Set the character encoding to UTF-8 to avoid issues with Unicode characters:

   ```
   chcp 65001
   ```
7. To get the list of all system-wide applications installed, run these commands:

   ```
   for /f "tokens=3,*" %A in ('"reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE2\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /v "DisplayName" /s | findstr /c:"REG_SZ" "') do @echo %A %B>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\list.txt"
   for /f "tokens=3,*" %A in ('"reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE2\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData" /v "DisplayName" /s | findstr /c:"REG_SZ" "') do @echo %A %B>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\list.txt"
   ```

   The list will be created on the desktop.
8. If the original system was 32-bit (x86), skip to step 9. Otherwise run the following command too:

   ```
   for /f "tokens=3,*" %A in ('"reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE2\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /v "DisplayName" /s | findstr /c:"REG_SZ" "') do @echo %A %B>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\list.txt"
   ```
9. Unload the machine registry hive:

   ```
   reg unload "HKLM\SOFTWARE2"
   ```
10. Load the user registry hive:

    ```
    reg load "HKU\User1" "X:\Path\to\NTUSER1.DAT"
    ```
11. Get the list of the per-user installed software:

    ```
    for /f "tokens=3,*" %A in ('"reg query "HKU\User1\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /v "DisplayName" /s | findstr /c:"REG_SZ" "') do @echo %A %B>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\list.txt"
    for /f "tokens=3,*" %A in ('"reg query "HKU\User1\Software\Microsoft\Installer" /v "ProductName" /s | findstr /c:"REG_SZ" "') do @echo %A %B>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\list.txt"
    ```

    If the required keys don't exist, that means there are no user-installed programs.
12. Unload the registry hive:

    ```
     reg unload "HKU\User1"
    ```
13. Repeat steps 10-12 for any other `NTUSERx.DAT` file.
14. Sort the resulting list alphabetically:

    ```
     sort "%UserProfile%\Desktop\list.txt" /o "%UserProfile%\Desktop\list.txt"
    ```

### Known issues

- Some applications may be listed more than once. That usually happens when they include several components which share the same display name.

## References

- [Command Prompt: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7)
- [for - Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx)
- [reg - Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx)
- [findstr - Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx)
- [Finding all installed programs from the registry](http://forum.sysinternals.com/finding-all-installed-programs-from-the-registry_topic21312.html)

Comment: Excellent! If the specified `Uninstall` key in the User hive does not exist, does that mean there are no programs installed only for that user?

Comment: @MilindR The `Uninstall` key is what gets queried (mostly) by the Programs and Features control panel applet to populate the software list. Anyway, I've edited the original answer in order to include [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) (MSI) installed programs. In case you followed all the steps already, repeat step 4 onwards. Let me know if you have any further doubts.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for making it so detailed. I could have managed with just the name of the key and attribute, but it will help others a great deal.

Answer (score 3):

Boot from Windows 7 DVD

repair

command prompt

dism  /Image:c:\  /Get-Apps  (Gets MSI installed programs.)

You should be able to run regedit from there.

Inside regedit use File Load Hive and select c:\windows\system32\config\SOFTWARE

export (First one 64 bit software, and 2nd is 32 bit software)

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Comment: There could also be user-installed programs which wouldn't be listed in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive.

Comment: @and31415 Also fully portable programs that you would normally run off a USB stick.  However, the above 2 registry locations should give 99 plus or minus a couple percent.

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt to consider the user registry hives, unless one can be sure they wouldn't list additional programs. Also, if the OP had some portable applications on a USB stick, those wouldn't be affected by a Windows reinstall. Either way, simply running `regedit` is not enough because you have to manually load the `C:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE` registry hive first in order to access the actual keys.

Comment: The `dism` command failed for me...