# List all installed software on PC with program data path

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

I'm trying to do the same thing as [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/447277/list-all-installed-software-on-pc) but want the path of the program data file path. I noticed that an app that I installed isn't appearing in the apps section of the settings app.

Comment: There is no requirement for the actual install locations.  In fact.. there is no standard (other than MSI) for the installer itself.  MSI has a vars called `TARGETDIR` and `INSTALLDIR` but even those can be changed many times during the installation process.. I am not trying to stop you in your quest but NOTHING will give you 100% what you are asking for.  The only actual "standard" is the location and command line for the uninstaller itself which can be found in the windows registry (and not all that helpful).  I have written windows installers (professionally) since win95.  GOOD LUCK!

Comment: You might find my answer in this post helpful as well: https://superuser.com/questions/1603763/how-can-i-run-a-single-command-to-show-all-installed-applications-in-windows-10/1603935#1603935

Comment: BTW, the free application Sumo, from https://kcsoftwares.com/?download, does a good job finding files in obscure locations. To avoid ads, download as the Zip file.